# loop infinito en python

Tags: python, bucles, raspberry-pi

trato de hacer un programita que funcione en Raspberry pi.
Les paso este código que funciona, pero solo una ves, necesito que sea infinito, luego veré de cómo salir de él.
La idea es recoger unos datos de una web, descargar un archivo flac y reproducirlo vía cmd.
Esto funciona correctamente. Les comento que en la Rasp tengo Volumio funcionando y lo hago todo via ssh con putty.
No logro crear un bucle infinito, en Python me quitaron el GOTO!!!!
Sepan comprender que es mi primer trabajo en Python, disculpen...
Va el link al código:
https://pastebin.com/1vwn8hjW

Answer (score 4):

Para hacer un bucle infinito tienes que poner una condición que siempre se cumpla. Por ejemplo: `while True`. Siempre será verdadero. Para poder salir más adelante, lo mejor es que la condición esté en una variable:

```py
condicion = True
while condicion:
    print('Infinito')
    # En algún momento, cuando quieras, haces: condicion = False

print('El fin de la eternidad') # Esta línea se ejecutará cuando condicion sea False.
```

Comment: Gracias, me es de mucha utilidad su ayuda, de a poco voy entendiendo como se hace.